# Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am trying to learn flutter, and this is a copy code from training, and I am not sure what to do to fix it.

Error:

Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:31:19: Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'.

- 'Key' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/key.dart').
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  ^^^
  lib/main.dart:31:29: Error: The parameter 'title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  ^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 27s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             90.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change  'MyHomePage({Key key, this.title})' to  'MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title})'. This is related to null-safety, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 1):

This is because of null safety. The Key should be nullable in the class and to make it nullable change `Key` to `Key?`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Learn more about null safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).